# Unpredictable results when using Parallel.For

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, task-parallel-library, amazon-sqs, parallel.foreach

I am running a Parallel for loop which initially runs for the times = number of processors and performs a long running operation. Each task when finished, checks for more tasks and if found, calls itself again.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Int32 numberOfProcessors = Environment.ProcessorCount;

   Parallel.For(0, numberOfProcessors, index => DoSomething(index, sqsQueueURL));

}

private async static Task DoSomething(int index, string queueURL)
{
   var receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest { QueueUrl = queueURL, WaitTimeSeconds = 20, MaxNumberOfMessages = 1, VisibilityTimeout = 1200 };

   AmazonSQSClient sqsClient = new AmazonSQSClient(new AmazonSQSConfig { MaxErrorRetry = 4 });

   var receiveMessageResponse = sqsClient.ReceiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest);

   foreach (var msg in receiveMessageResponse.Messages)
   {
      PerformALongRunningTask......

      //delete the message

      DeleteMessageRequest deleteMessageRequest = new DeleteMessageRequest(queueURL, msg.ReceiptHandle);

      AmazonSQSClient sqsDeleteClient = new AmazonSQSClient();

      sqsDeleteClient.DeleteMessage(deleteMessageRequest);

      //Do it again
      DoSometing(index,queueURL)

   }
}
```

I am getting very unpredictable results. It never completes all the tasks. It exits before completing everything.

What am i doing wrong here?

Shorter Code:

```
static Int32 TimesToLoop = 143;
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Int32 numberOfProcessors = Environment.ProcessorCount;

    Parallel.For(0, numberOfProcessors, index => DoSomething(index));

    Console.Read();
}

private async static Task DoSomething(int index)
{
    if(TimesToLoop == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(index);
    Interlocked.Decrement(ref TimesToLoop);
    DoSomething(index++);
    return;

}
```

Comment: First thing to do: reduce this to a short but complete example which doesn't involve Amazon Web Services at all. The problem is with your use of `Parallel.For`. Making your method just print "starting" and the index, then awaiting `Thread.Delay`, then print "ending" and the index will demonstrate the same problem, with fewer dependencies and less code.

Comment: Does your real code actually contain `await` expressions, by the way? If it doesn't, each call to your `DoSomething` method will run synchronously...

Comment: No. it doesnt. Don't know how to use await in Parallel.For

Comment: I was asking about your `DoSomething` method, which you've marked as an `async` method, but which doesn't contain `await` expressions, including when calling it recursively. It sounds like you may need to read up more on async/await...

Comment: Inside DoSomething, i have other operations that contain await.

Comment: Right, that's what I was trying to ask in the second comment...

Answer (score 4):

I see various problems at the moment:

- `Parallel.For` is just starting the tasks. It won't wait for them to complete. It will wait for the `DoSomething` method calls to return, but they're returning tasks representing the asynchronous operations, which probably won't have completed synchronously.
- As CarbineCoder noted, your recursion is almost certainly flawed. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but you need to rethink that aspect
- Your recursion doesn't `await` the tasks returned anyway - it almost certainly should. It *might* want to create a collection of all the tasks created in the `foreach` loop and await them all in one go, or it might want to `await` them immediately. We can't tell.

The simplest way of fixing the first part is probably to use `Task.WaitAll` instead of `Parallel.For`:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfProcessors)
                      .Select(index => DoSomething(index, sqsQueueURL))
                      .ToList();
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Unlike `Task.WhenAll`, `Task.WaitAll` will block until all the specified tasks have completed. Note that this is *not* safe to do if any of the tasks need to continue on the thread calling `WaitAll`, precisely because it blocks - but if this is a console application and you're calling this from the initial thread, you'll be okay as the continuations will execute on the thread pool anyway.

Comment: what i am trying to do is as soon as one task finishes, it should start a new one as there will be many tasks. I am trying to limit the number of tasks equals to the number of processors. When there are no more messages left to process, it should terminate.

Comment: @Asdfg: I suggest you don't do that. You're calling web services - you're not going to be CPU limited anyway. Even if you only have a single processor, you can have 100 requests to the web service in flight at the same time. Do you have *working* code at all yet? Before you start trying to fine-tune this, get it working as simply as possible.,

Comment: True but i am running multiple nodes so i do not want to lock the message if it is going to wait for other tasks to finish.

Comment: @Asdfg: I'm afraid I don't know what the context for that comment was... it doesn't seem to have anything to do with my previous comment. I've explained the behaviour you're seeing, but I really think you need to take a step back to think more carefully about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Appreciate your help. I converted everything back to Synchronous and it is working. I will tackle the multi threading beast later.

Answer (score 1):

```
private async static Task DoSomething(int index, string queueURL)
{
   ...
   foreach (var msg in receiveMessageResponse.Messages)
   {
      ...
      //Do it again
      DoSometing(index,queueURL)

   }
}
```

You are calling `DoSomething` recursively and there is no condition to break/return out of it. It might lead to stackoverflow and terminate your program.

Comment: it is. just noticed that

Comment: @carbinecoder  there is a condition to break/return right? when there are no messages in receiveMessageResponse.Messages

Comment: True I missed that,  I agree with you polling should be done till `receiveMessageResponse.Messages` is available  but it need not be a recursive call.